# Video not playing on Django when debug=False

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

Videos are not playing when I turn DEBUG to False on Django, but on DEBUG=True, everything is fine.
The task is simple, the app receives youtube shorts link, downloads it to the MEDIA_ROOT (which declared in settings.py as BASE_DIR / 'media'). And it returns rendered template `video.html`, on template:

`<video height="450" autoplay="autoplay" controls style=""> <br> <source src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file }}" type="{{ mime_type }}">`
on html : 
`<video height="450" autoplay="autoplay" controls style="">`

`<source src="/media/filename.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

views:
`{"MEDIA_URL": MEDIA_URL, "file": str(video.video).split('/')[-1],}`

settings.py:

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`
`MEDIA_ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'media'`

As I said when debug mode turned on everything works perfect, but I turned it off video is not playing. Did I forget something? Or any mistake I have? how to solve this problem?

P.S. I am pretty new on django, I searched for many sources, tried them all, but I couldn't solve this problem

Comment: I forgot to say django version is 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not support file serving in production ([have a look here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)). The helper function "+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) " works only in debug mode.  Therefore it cannot read the file from media.

If you want to use the file in production with  `debug=False`, try to switch to another [storage backend](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or serve it from elsewhere.